# Associate Content to a custom data source to Sitecore SXA promo component

Tags: sxa

we are team trying to build our first Sitecore SXA website , we need to create a promo component for an article page (article template), my component looks similar to this

[image]

what would be the best approach to achieve this?, we have tried using the promo component but unable to figure our associating custom data source template and location for the promo how do we associate a custom datasource template and location for the promo component ?

Comment: You already posted similar question. Why there is need for this one? Gert already answered the former question. Just follow his advice and you can achieve a promo like on your picture

Comment: I have not posted a similar question